# HDMI Multi-Stream Transport

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I was trying to understand the differences between DisplayPort and HDMI. I
noticed that DisplayPort supports Multi-Stream Transport (MST), which:

> It allows multiple independent displays to be driven from a single DP port on
> the source devices by multiplexing several video streams into a single stream
> and sending it to a branch device, which demultiplexes the signal into the
> original streams. Branch devices are commonly found in the form of an MST hub,
> which plugs into a single DP input port and provides multiple outputs, but it
> can also be implemented on a display internally to provide a DP output port
> for daisy-chaining, effectively embedding a 2-port MST hub inside the display.

https://wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multiple_displays_on_single_DisplayPort_connector

Does HDMI support something similar to this? Something like an HDMI "MST hub"
or HDMI "daisy chain"?

Comment: No. (minimum character limit...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From HDMI 2.0 on, you get up to four audio streams and two video streams (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Feature_support)), but nothing like the complicated topology management that's possible with DP.

If you want to understand the differences, think historically: HDMI originally was DVI for consumer electronics with additional copy protection and a different plug. DisplayPort came a bit later, and was intended as a generic way to attach monitors to PCs etc, with the intention to replace DVI. But of course both gained features over time.

Comment: thank you - so what would that look like equipment wise? Do you have any examples

Comment: What exactly do you mean "equipment wise"? TVs have HDMI connectors, but normally not DP. Computer monitors started with DVI, gained HDMI for convenience, and now also have DP.